# How do we make this query fast in MySQL 5.5 (group by + order by multiple columns with 2 left joins)?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, sql-order-by

Table type: InnoDB
MySQL 5.5 (Debian 7.0)

We have this query:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE t.*, count(ul.user_id) AS like_count FROM post p
force index (added_utc_date_and_time_sort_idx)
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_post_liked ul ON p.id = ul.post_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_post u ON u.post_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY p.added_utc_date ASC, p.added_utc_time ASC, p.hash ASC LIMIT 0,10;
```

There are indexes added_utc_date_and_time_sort_idx(p.added_utc_date, p.added_utc_time, p.hash), primary(post.id)

The EXPLAIN shows a temp table and file sort, with the query taking about 4 seconds with only 20K rows/200MB of data (very slow as we will have 2 million+ rows == 400+ seconds query time):

```
id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys,    key,              key_len, ref,  rows,  Extra

1,  SIMPLE,      p,     ALL,  NULL,             NULL,             NULL,    NULL, 24576, "Using temporary; Using filesort"

1,  SIMPLE,      ul,    ref,  PRIMARY,          PRIMARY,          764,     posta.p.id,1,"Using index"

1,  SIMPLE,      u,     ref,  fk_user_post_idx, fk_user_post_idx, 764,     posta.p.id,1,"Using index"
```

Now what we want is for mysql to use the index to order the rows instead of doing a filesort since we are only reading the first 10 results.

Comment: you might only be reading the first 10 result rows of the query, but mysql still has to SORT  all 2+ million rows to figure out what those first 10 rows should be.

Comment: We added a multicolumn index specifically targeting the order by clause of this query so that mysql does not need to do the sort.

Comment: Forcing the use of indexes is bad idea. You are trying to outsmart the query optimizer. Not recommended.

Comment: We initially tried the query without the force index as below but because the query was taking so long we tried to force the index on it. Please note that EXPLAIN gives us the SAME execution plan in both cases (with and without the force index). if trying to get MySQL to use the index is not the right direction we are eager to try any other methods that can be suggested to make this query fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the combination of `GROUP BY` with `ORDER BY`. There is no single index that would cover both!

To make it work without sorting, you'd need **one** index that satisfies the order required for `GROUP BY` (`p.id`) as as well as the order required for the `ORDER BY` (`p.added_utc_date ASC, p.added_utc_time ASC, p.hash ASC`). These two order requirements don't share a common prefix, hence you cannot have a **single** index that supports both.

If, however, you could do with `ORDER BY p.id, p.added_utc_date, ...` then you could create an index for that and it should work for both (still I don't know if MySQL is smart enough to do it!).

To make a long story short: the execution plan you are thinking of is impossible for your query.

References:

- [Indexed `ORDER BY`](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/sorting-grouping/indexed-order-by)
- [Indexed `GROUP BY`](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/sorting-grouping/indexed-group-by)

Comment: After we added a second index (id, date, time, hash) MySQL was able to use the indexes to evaluate the query.